# "Dumbed Down" Definition Behind Factor Groups and Computing Them

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm confusing myself trying to understand what factor groups really are. I see that the formal definition is:

If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then the group of left cosets of $N$ form a group under the coset multiplication given by $aN$ $bN$ = $ab N$. This is called the factor group of $G$ determined by $N$, denoted by $G/N.$

If I'm understanding it correctly, then is a factor group simply "just the set of all left cosets of $N$" (as long as $N$ is normal)? If so, then my understanding of computing said $G/N$ would be to:

1) Check $N$ really is a normal subgroup of $G$. (left cosets of $N$ = right cosets of $N$, $N$ satisfies all axioms of a subgroup).

2) Compute all left cosets of $N$. (this is where I'm having some trouble as well; how do you know which cosets are the "correct" left cosets?)

3) Put them all in a set s.t. $S$ = $G/N$.

Is this correct? I feel like this is way too simple, and couldn't really apply it. For example, I was on a problem that asked:

Compute the factor group ($\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_8$) / <($1, 2$)>.

In this case, how I couldn't really start on finding the left cosets of <($1, 2$)>, or how to put them together as a factor group.

I know this question kind of seems overloaded, but I feel like I'm $so$ close to really hitting that "ding" on factor groups. Any help would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Different left cosets $gN$ are disjoint from each other (this is not special for normal subgroups -- it works for left cosets of any subgroup).  So to "compute" that quotient group you ask about, pick an element of the big group $\mathbf Z/(4) \times \mathbf Z/(8)$ and add it to all the elements of $\langle (1,2)\rangle$ to get a coset.  Check if you filled up the whole original group; you haven't. So pick an element of the big group not yet found in your coset and form *its* left coset (well, the big group is abelian so left vs. right is pointless).  Keep going until you fill up the group.

Comment: Then you count how many cosets you find and you now know the size of the quotient group. Then you want to, I suppose, understand the group structure. Start adding some representatives of cosets and see what new cosets you get to determine, say, if your quotient group is cyclic or not.

Comment: You may enjoy these simple interactive web programs for investigating [subgroups](http://mathcs.holycross.edu/~ahwang/teach/common/software/algebra/Subgroups/index.html) and [cosets](http://mathcs.holycross.edu/~ahwang/teach/common/software/algebra/Cosets/index.html) in $\mathbf{Z}_{m} \times \mathbf{Z}_{n}$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is perhaps an alternative way to think about it.

The factor group is the group we get when we ignore elements of the normal subgroup $N$. So we want the elements $g$ and $gh$ to be the same if $h\in N$, and we want to be able to multiply elements while preserving this property. You can always define the equivalence relation required for this (the equivalence classes are the left cosets) but in order to multiply them you need $N$ to be normal. Here's why; people make it out to be this really deep concept, but it's silly algebraic manipulation.

Let $a,b\in G$ and $g,h\in N$. We want to be able to say that $ab$ is equivalent to $(ag)(bh)$, in that they are in the same left coset. Rewrite this as
$$(ag)(bh)=ab(b^{-1}gb)h$$
In order for this to be equivalent to $ab$ it must be the case that $(b^{-1}gb)h\in N$. Since $h\in N$, this means that the condition is that $b^{-1}gb\in N$ for all $b\in G$ and $g\in N$. This is very often taken as the definition of a normal subgroup, and this is the reason.

For the definition you seem to be using, we require that the left cosets be the same as the right cosets so we can move the $g$ past the $b$. We need to know that
$$gb=bg'$$
for some $g'\in N$. This means that
$$(ag)(bh)=abg'h$$
which gets us to the same place, but it's less specific. It happens that $g'=b^{-1}gb$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't like the phrase "ignore elements of the normal subgroup $N$", but I know what you mean and struggle to find a better wording. Otherwise your answer is as usual very nice (+1). The point is that one wants to keep the operation on the elements, but changes the point of view about which elements are considered equal (as you write in your 3rd sentence). The condition for normal subgroup is then forced (as you show).